# R pivot_longer with stub names and by last underscore

Tags: r, tidyr

I have the following stylized wide data frame, `df_wide`, that I would like to reshape long in `R`:

```
df_wide = data.frame(country = c("A", "B"),
                gdp_1999 = c(100, 200),
                gdp_2000 = c(400,500),
                poverty_rate_1999 = c(35,40),
                poverty_rate_2000 = c(10,15),
                inequality_score_gini_1999 = c(20,25),
                inequality_score_gini_2000 = c(40,45)
                )
df_wide
  country gdp_1999 gdp_2000 poverty_rate_1999 poverty_rate_2000 inequality_score_gini_1999 inequality_score_gini_2000
1       A      100      400                35                10                         20                         40
2       B      200      500                40                15                         25                         45
```

I would like to use `pivot_longer` to reshape the data long by country-year, such that the data frame looks like this:

```
df_long = data.frame(country = c("A","A","B","B"),
                     year = c(1999,1999,2000,2000),
                     gdp = c(100,400,200,500),
                     poverty_rate = c(35,10,40,15),
                     inequality_score_gini = c(20,40,25,45))
df_long
country year gdp poverty_rate inequality_score_gini
1       A 1999 100           35                    20
2       A 1999 400           10                    40
3       B 2000 200           40                    25
4       B 2000 500           15                    45
```

How would I do that with `pivot_longer`? Kindly note that I have specifically picked variables with different numbers of underscores, because that is where related [past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59178736/using-r-for-reshape-with-name-stubs) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65791421/complexish-pivot-longer-in-r) don't provide adequate guidance for my dataset. The best I can do is with regular `reshape`, reshaping one stub pattern at a time, such as:

```
library(reshape)
long_data_gdp <- reshape(df_wide, 
                     varying = c("gdp_1999", "gdp_2000"),
                     idvar = "country",
                     direction = "long",
                     sep = "_")
```

I would really appreciate if the correct answer could provide two sub-answers: (1) an answer with `starts_with()` so everything could be done by stub names instead of `names_pattern`, because my attempt above with `reshape` fails when there is more than one underscore separator (i.e., `poverty_rate` and `inequality_gini_score` don't work); (2) an answer with `names_pattern` but that explains how to target the last underscore as a separator in a way that is easy for non-`regex` experts to understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answers the `names_pattern` approach:

The trick is to use a regex which sets up the two groups: (1) all value variables `(.*)` and (2) the year variable `([0-9]{4})`. We need to use brackets to specify the groups.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df_wide %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = !country,
               names_to = c(".value", "year"),
               names_pattern = "^(.*)_([0-9]{4})$")

#> # A tibble: 4 × 5
#>   country year    gdp poverty_rate inequality_score_gini
#>   <chr>   <chr> <dbl>        <dbl>                 <dbl>
#> 1 A       1999    100           35                    20
#> 2 A       2000    400           10                    40
#> 3 B       1999    200           40                    25
#> 4 B       2000    500           15                    45
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Below the data:

```r
df_wide <- tribble(~country, ~gdp_1999, ~gdp_2000, ~poverty_rate_1999, ~poverty_rate_2000, ~inequality_score_gini_1999, ~inequality_score_gini_2000,
                   "A",      100,      400,                35,                10,                         20,                         40,
                   "B",      200,      500,                40,                15,                         25,                         45)
```

Comment: Thank you, @TimTeaFan! The solution clearly works and is very clever. A couple questions: 1) any tips on how to easily learn `regex` so I can think for myself next time? The `names_pattern` solutions always confuse me. 2) Is there any way to do this with `starts_with` or by manually specifying the stub names before the year at the end--kind of like what I started with `reshape` but able to handle variables with multiple underscores?

Comment: Regarding (1): I like playing around with [regex101](https://regex101.com). Further [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/ziishaned/learn-regex) is short and helpful.

Comment: Regarding (2) and the general approach with `starts_with`: I'm not sure if I understand how your desired  approach should look like. We can use  `starts_with` and other tidy select syntax in the `col` argument. We can also use regex here with `matches()`. Can you specify how a answer with `pivot_longer` should look like (even if the code might not be working)?

Comment: basically, instead of using the `".value"`, you would use something like `starts_with("gdp", "poverty_rate", "inequality_score_gini")` . Basically, what I tried to do with `reshape` above but failed because of the multiple underscores.